# How can I make my bottom nav slide up and down with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to keep the nav on the bottom of the page while being able to show it and hide it. For some reason I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The toggle is fixed but now I'm having troubles with the fluidity. When I use the toggle the boxes are not at the same speed.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hg2ax/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-footer').click(function() {        
       $('#footer-content').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your float on the footer right is screwing it up. Add the float to both and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Hg2ax/4/

Comment: Worked awesome! Thanks! One small issue... If you look at the left box it's not touch the end of the page. EDIT: I figured it out! I was missing left:0; Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just take the height off of your footer css.

```
footer {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg2ax/5/

Comment: That definitely helped! Thanks! Why does the boxes get all messed up and the Menu is seperated from the other boxes :\

Comment: Because your CSS doesn't tell it not to.  ;)

Comment: Haha well I got rid of the padding and that seemed to help a little bit but there seems to be 2 problems now.

1. when you use the toggle one of the boxes is slower then the other
2. the menu is not touching the boxes

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg2ax/2/

Comment: Or yeah, just the extra float was necessary, not all that extra horrible code.